# Windows 10 on Dual Boot System with Debian 9 won't shutdown properly

Tags: linux, windows-10, debian, multi-boot

Some days ago, I installed Windows 10 and Debian 9 Stretch as Dual Boot on my system. All went fine and I was able to boot both systems without any problems.

Both system work (almost) perfectly - except Windows. I noticed that I can't shutdown windows. Everytime I select "shutdown" via Windows Key -> Powersymbole -> Shutdown, Windows just turns off the screen - that's all what happens. If there are updates to install, there's a different behavior: Windows gets into it's "update screen", and shuts down after the update is installed. If you start the computer again and select Windows to boot, Windows tells that the update wasn't successful and it will try to recovery the latest save point. After that step, it's still the same: Windows can't shutdown down, only the screen turns off.

I can't explain this because Debian 9 works perfectly.

I guess that the problem lies in the way I installed both systems. I did it like the following:

- I split the harddrive into two same-sized partitions
- First, I installed Windows on partition 1
- Secondly, I installed Debian 9 on partition 2 and installed Grub into the 
  Master Record
- I booted both system and set up the systems to work on them

I guess that the error lies in these steps, but as I said I'm not sure.

**Is there a way how I can fix this error?**

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You mentioned "master record." Is it booting via UEFI or legacy? How did the system work before you installed Windows and Debian?

Comment: @jdwolf Before I installed Debian and Windows, I had just Windows installed. That worked without any problems. To answer your first question, it boots via UEFI.

Comment: what happens if you hold shift and power down

Comment: @Joe I encountered to cases: If Windows tries to install updates, the problem continues - Windows can't install them properly. If there aren't any updates, holding the Shift-key and powering down works - Windows shuts down just as it should. So there's only one problem left. But anyway, thank you for the trick!

Comment: If holding shift works then its related to fast start-up. Holding shift makes it power down instead of hibernate. So that suggests hibernating didn't work and may still not work. It's possible that after installing Windows the partition was resized to install Linux? The slightly worse possibility is data loss because Linux doesn't handle NTFS properly if its in a hibernated state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows [saves system state to HDD to speed up booting](https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/), not only when *Hibernate* is enabled, but also if *Fast Startup*, or 'hybrid shutdown' is set. These files, e.g. *hiberfil.sys*, can cause problems when dual-booting, so disable *Fast Startup* in the *Power Options* dialog.
*Hibernate* can be enabled or disabled from the CMD prompt or batch file (executed as Administrator), which may be convenient if you use that feature frequently but still want to boot to Linux:

> powercfg -h off

To ensure full shutdown rather than hybrid, you can use the following command:

> shutdown /s /t 0

Both commands can be combined into a single batch file.